# How to iterate over functions with a different number of arguments

Tags: python, function, dictionary, arguments, partial

I want to iterate over a number of functions that are stored in a dictionary as :

```
function_dict = {'func_a': partial(func_a),
                 'func_b': partial(func_b)}
```

Let's say for simplicity that these functions are:

```
def func_a(x,y):
    return x + y

def func_b(x):
    return x**2
```

In fact, these functions are part of an external library, so I cannot modify them.

I want to be able to loop through all of them. However, `func_a` receives 2 arguments while `func_b` receives 1 argument.

I want to do the following:

```
x = 2
y = 5

for key, func in function_dict.items():
    
    if (key=='func_a'):

        print( (func)(x,y) )

    if (key=='func_b'):

        print( (func)(x) )
```

which yields

```
7
4
```

In this loop I have used the if-statement to see which function is coming up and use the appropriate number of arguments. But this is unusable if there are too many functions in the `function_dict`.

How can i standardize it so that I can loop through all the functions in the dictionary and pick up the correct number of arguments for each of them ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How would it pick *what* arguments to use? And what's your point of using `partial` without any arguments?

Comment: My intention is to be able to pick up the correct argument and number of arguments by keyword. So if an "x" or a "y" is required it should be added to the signature. Is there a way around this without if-statements ? [You are correct, the "partial" is in fact not necessary]

Comment: This kind of smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why do you want to iterate over the functions in a dictionary? Your example code doesn't make it immediately obvious why this is necessary. Why not simply invoke the functions normally? Since you're using partials already anyways, why not bind the required parameters in your `function_dict` definition? I think it would help if you had a more concrete example of what you're actually trying to do, rather than dummy code. Also, not all versions of Python 3.+ guarantee ordered dictionaries.

Comment: I am using a dictionary because I want to use Parallel() from joblib and parallelize the loop over all functions. This requires an iterable like a dictionary. In order to postpone the evaluation of the function till the call of Parallel I have used partial. That's why I do not invoke it.